# Get specific data from within a join and also outside of the join

Tags: mysql, join

So I am looking to extract data from various tables. the tables are joined together but currently I am seeing many duplicates.

Here are the tables I am using:
courseuser: gets the course information for a user
user: gets user information (username)
course_session: provides the sessions for a course (1 course can have multiple sessions)
courseuser_session: provides information showing which user id is connected to which session id (1 user can have 0 or more sessions associated, this table would only show a record if there is a minimum of 1 session associated to a user)

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT
u.userid as User_id,
u.user as Username,
lcu.courseid as Course_id,

lcus.sessionid as Session_id
from courseuser lcu
LEFT JOIN user u ON lcu.id = u.id

LEFT JOIN course_session lcs ON lcu.courseid = lcs.courseid

LEFT JOIN courseuser_session lcus ON lcs.sessionid = lcus.sessionid AND lcu.userid = lcus.userid
where u.userid = '205069';
```

**sorry if the data in the tables doesnt format well**
sample data:

courseuser:

| userid | courseid | additional data not associated.. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 205069 | 8 | - |
| 205069 | 47 | - |

user:

| userid | user | additional data not associated.. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 205069 | Tim | - |

course_session:

| sessionid | courseid | additional data not associated.. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 70 | 8 | - |
| 10 | 8 | - |
| 66 | 8 | - |

courseuser_session:

| sessionid | userid | additional data not associated.. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 70 | 20569 | - |

The user **205069** is only on 1 session for 1 course.
The above sql query returns all of the  other sessions for that course also even though the user is not on it.

I would like an output where it shows only the session the user is on AND
because some courses do not have sessions, I want to show the courses also which are associated to the user, it can fill the session column with NULL if it does not exist.

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
LEFT JOIN courseuser_session lcus ON lcs.sessionid = lcus.sessionid AND lcu.userid = lcus.userid
```

by this one

```
INNER JOIN courseuser_session lcus ON lcs.sessionid = lcus.sessionid AND lcu.userid = lcus.userid
```

Comment: I have tried this, it returns only the row where the session exists for the user, it does not include the other courses associated to the user